# Graph disconnected when trying to create models in Keras with .get_layer method

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, keras-layer

In the normal code, I do something like this, and everything works fine:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

X, y = make_blobs(500,50,2)

def make_network1():
    input_layer = Input((50,))
    layer1 = Dense(100,name='network1_dense1')(input_layer)
    output = Dense(50,name='network1_dense2')(layer1)
    model = Model(input_layer,output)

    return model

def make_network2():
    input_layer = Input((50,))
    layer1 = Dense(100,name='network2_dense1')(input_layer)
    output = Dense(1,name='network2_output')(layer1)
    model = Model(input_layer,output)

    return model

network1 = make_network1()
network2 = make_network2()
output = network2(network1.output)

model = Model(network1.input, output)
```

Now, I want to experiment with the `.get_layer` method and `.output` attribute in Keras by replacing the last line of code with:

```
model = Model(network1.input, network2.get_layer('network2_output').output)
```

Then it gives me the following error:

> Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor
>   Tensor("input_4:0", shape=(?, 50), dtype=float32) at layer "input_4".
>   The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

### My Question

However, shouldn't be `output` and `network2.get_layer('network2_output').output` the same thing? When I try to print both of them out, it says:

> Tensor("model_14/network2_output/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)

and

> Tensor("network2_output_1/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)

And `network2` has been connected to the output of `network1` already, I don't get why it is disconnected. How to make the code works with the `.get_layer` and `.output` methods?

I am using keras==2.24 and tensorflow-gpu==1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running this line:

```
output = network2(network1.output)
```

the `network2` model has two computation flows: one is the original one constructed when running `make_network2()`, and another is the computation flow with `network1.output` as the input constructed when running the above line. Therefore, it would have two outputs corresponding to each of these two computation flows:

```
>>> network2.get_output_at(0)
<tf.Tensor 'network2_output_4/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>

>>> network2.get_output_at(1)
<tf.Tensor 'model_14/network2_output/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>
```

Therefore, when you want to go from the `network1.input` to the output of `network2` model, you must use the second output which is connected to the `network1.input`:

```
model = Model(network1.input, network2.get_output_at(1))
```

Essentially, `network2.get_output_at(1)` is equivalent to `output` obtained in this line: `output = network2(network1.output)`.

Comment: I understand it now. How about if I want to get the output for the middle layer? I can't find any equivalent of `.get_layer_output_at()`.  Just curious if similar things can be done to the middle layers instead of the final output layer.

Comment: @RavenCheuk No, because you have applied the whole `network2` model on the `network1.output` and since the `Model` class inherits from `Layer` class in Keras, it could be individually applied on tensors. Further, the call method for the models is implemented such that the internal attributes of the middle layers are not updated; rather they are only called to get their output. So we only have access to the new symbolic output of the model, and not those of its middle layers.

Answer (score 1):

> shouldn't be output and network2.get_layer('network2_output').output
>   the same thing?

No!, they are not the same thing.
Let me explain what is happening here

```
network1 = make_network1()
network2 = make_network2()
output = network2(network1.output)
```

First you are creating two model's with one input for each layer and then you are replacing the second model's input with last layers output of the first model. This way you are making inputs of the `output` variable to be the first model's input. So the `network1.inputs` and `output` are connected.
But on the following line there is no connection between `network1.input` and `network2.get_layer('network2_output').output`

```
model = Model(network1.input, network2.get_layer('network2_output').output)
```

Comment: Is it possible to force the new input as the sole input of network2? I want to create my neural network by piecing several components (1 function 1 component) together. However, I am not sure if it is the correct way to do so